# do-release-upgrade aborting

Tags: upgrade

Edit - Same thing happens attempting to upgrade to 21.10 - this is not specific to Jammy.

Not really sure why this is aborting, I can't really see the problem in the logs:

```
2022-03-07 23:49:02,329 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg.focal', '/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.d/ubuntu-advantage-upgrades.cfg']'
2022-03-07 23:49:02,329 INFO uname information: 'Linux sodorstation 5.15.0-18-generic #18-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 21 14:57:54 UTC 2022 x86_64'
2022-03-07 23:49:02,544 INFO apt version: '2.0.6'
2022-03-07 23:49:02,545 INFO python version: '3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08) 
[GCC 9.3.0]'
2022-03-07 23:49:02,547 INFO release-upgrader version '22.04.5' started
2022-03-07 23:49:02,554 INFO locale: 'en_AU' 'UTF-8'
2022-03-07 23:49:02,592 INFO screen could not be run
2022-03-07 23:49:02,625 DEBUG Using 'DistUpgradeViewText' view
2022-03-07 23:49:02,661 DEBUG enable dpkg --force-overwrite
2022-03-07 23:49:02,688 DEBUG creating statefile: '/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-clone_system_state.tar.gz'
2022-03-07 23:49:03,652 DEBUG lsb-release: 'focal'
2022-03-07 23:49:03,652 DEBUG _pythonSymlinkCheck run
2022-03-07 23:49:03,653 DEBUG openCache()
2022-03-07 23:49:03,653 DEBUG quirks: running PreCacheOpen
2022-03-07 23:49:03,653 DEBUG running Quirks.PreCacheOpen
2022-03-07 23:49:04,152 DEBUG Comparing 5.13.0-30 with 
2022-03-07 23:49:04,152 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-18 with 5.13.0-30
2022-03-07 23:49:04,232 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 66479
2022-03-07 23:49:04,233 DEBUG need_server_mode(): can not find a desktop meta package or key deps, running in server mode
2022-03-07 23:49:04,233 DEBUG checkViewDepends()
2022-03-07 23:49:04,234 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=False)
2022-03-07 23:49:04,779 DEBUG openCache()
2022-03-07 23:49:05,287 DEBUG Comparing 5.13.0-30 with 
2022-03-07 23:49:05,287 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-18 with 5.13.0-30
2022-03-07 23:49:05,401 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 66479
2022-03-07 23:49:05,401 DEBUG doPostInitialUpdate
2022-03-07 23:49:05,401 DEBUG quirks: running jammyPostInitialUpdate
2022-03-07 23:49:05,401 DEBUG running Quirks.jammyPostInitialUpdate
2022-03-07 23:49:08,840 DEBUG MetaPkgs: 
2022-03-07 23:49:09,822 DEBUG Foreign: 
2022-03-07 23:49:09,822 DEBUG Obsolete: containerd.io docker-ce docker-ce-cli docker-ce-rootless-extras docker-scan-plugin libbind9-160 libboost-iostreams1.71.0 libcbor0.6 libdns-export1100 libdns-export1109 libdns1100 libevent-2.1-6 libffi6 libfwupdplugin1 libgdbm5 libhavege1 libhogweed4 libhogweed5 libicu60 libicu66 libip4tc0 libip6tc0 libirs160 libisc-export169 libisc169 libisccc160 libisccfg160 libisl22 libjson-c3 libjson-c4 libldap-2.4-2 libllvm10 liblvm2app2.2 liblvm2cmd2.02 liblwres160 libmpdec2 libnettle6 libnettle7 libperl5.26 libperl5.30 libplymouth4 libprocps6 libpython3.6-minimal libpython3.6-stdlib libpython3.8 libpython3.8-dev libpython3.8-minimal libpython3.8-stdlib libqrencode3 libreadline5 libreadline7 libsemanage1 libsepol1 libssl1.0.0 libtss2-esys0 libxmlb1 linux-headers-5.13.0-30-generic linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-30 linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic linux-modules-5.13.0-30-generic linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-30-generic mariadb-client-10.3 mariadb-client-core-10.3 mariadb-server-10.3 mariadb-server-core-10.3 multiarch-support nessus nessusagent perl-modules-5.26 perl-modules-5.30 postgresql-12 postgresql-client-12 python-pip-whl python3-twisted-bin python3.6 python3.6-minimal python3.8 python3.8-dev python3.8-minimal python3.8-venv veeam veeam-release-deb veeamsnap
2022-03-07 23:49:09,822 DEBUG updateSourcesList()
2022-03-07 23:49:09,826 DEBUG rewriteSourcesList() with mirror_check
2022-03-07 23:49:09,827 DEBUG ['ubuntu-minimal', 'ubuntu-standard']
2022-03-07 23:49:09,827 DEBUG Checking pkg: ubuntu-minimal
2022-03-07 23:49:09,827 DEBUG Checking pkg: ubuntu-standard
2022-03-07 23:49:09,827 DEBUG examining: 'deb [arch=amd64] http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse'
2022-03-07 23:49:09,827 DEBUG entry 'deb [arch=amd64] http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse' is already set to new dist
2022-03-07 23:49:09,827 DEBUG examining: 'deb [arch=amd64] http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse'
2022-03-07 23:49:09,827 DEBUG entry 'deb [arch=amd64] http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse' is already set to new dist
2022-03-07 23:49:09,827 DEBUG examining: 'deb [arch=amd64] http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse'
2022-03-07 23:49:09,828 DEBUG entry 'deb [arch=amd64] http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse' is already set to new dist
2022-03-07 23:49:09,828 DEBUG examining: 'deb [arch=amd64] http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse'
2022-03-07 23:49:09,828 DEBUG entry 'deb [arch=amd64] http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse' is already set to new dist
2022-03-07 23:49:09,858 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=True)
2022-03-07 23:49:10,383 DEBUG openCache()
2022-03-07 23:49:11,554 DEBUG Comparing 5.13.0-30 with 
2022-03-07 23:49:11,554 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-18 with 5.13.0-30
2022-03-07 23:49:11,650 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 66479
2022-03-07 23:49:11,651 DEBUG need_server_mode(): can not find a desktop meta package or key deps, running in server mode
2022-03-07 23:49:11,652 DEBUG quirks: running PreDistUpgradeCache
2022-03-07 23:49:11,652 DEBUG running Quirks.PreDistUpgradeCache
2022-03-07 23:49:12,257 DEBUG Installing 'libsemanage2' (priority in required set 'required' but not scheduled for install)
2022-03-07 23:49:12,257 ERROR Installing/upgrading 'libsemanage2' failed
2022-03-07 23:49:12,556 DEBUG Installing 'usrmerge' (priority in required set 'required' but not scheduled for install)
2022-03-07 23:49:12,556 ERROR Installing/upgrading 'usrmerge' failed
2022-03-07 23:49:12,586 DEBUG Running KeepInstalledSection rules
2022-03-07 23:49:13,021 DEBUG Kernel uname: '5.15.0-18-generic' 
2022-03-07 23:49:13,029 DEBUG nvidiaUpdate()
2022-03-07 23:49:13,644 INFO no old nvidia driver installed, installing no new
2022-03-07 23:49:13,645 DEBUG quirks: running PostDistUpgradeCache
2022-03-07 23:49:13,645 DEBUG running Quirks.PostDistUpgradeCache
2022-03-07 23:49:13,762 DEBUG Comparing 5.13.0-30 with 
2022-03-07 23:49:13,762 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-18 with 5.13.0-30
2022-03-07 23:49:13,904 DEBUG running installTasks
2022-03-07 23:49:14,610 DEBUG About to apply the following changes
2022-03-07 23:49:14,864 DEBUG Keep at same version: acl acpi-support acpid adduser adwaita-icon-theme alsa-topology-conf alsa-ucm-conf amd64-microcode anacron apparmor apparmor-profiles apparmor-utils apt apt-transport-https apt-utils aptitude aptitude-common base-files base-passwd bash bash-completion bcache-tools bind9-dnsutils bind9-host bind9-libs binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu borgbackup bsdmainutils bsdutils btrfs-progs build-essential busybox-initramfs busybox-static bzip2 ca-certificates chrony clamav clamav-base clamav-daemon clamav-freshclam clamdscan console-setup console-setup-linux containerd.io coreutils cpio cpp cpp-9 cpufrequtils cracklib-runtime crda cron cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin cryptsetup-initramfs cryptsetup-run curl dash db-util db5.3-util dbus dbus-user-session dbus-x11 dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service dctrl-tools debconf debconf-i18n debianutils deborphan dialog diffutils dirmngr distro-info distro-info-data dkms dmeventd dmidecode dmsetup dns-root-data dnsmasq dnsmasq-base dnsutils docker-ce docker-ce-cli docker-ce-rootless-extras docker-scan-plugin dpkg dpkg-dev e2fsprogs efibootmgr eject ethtool fail2ban fakeroot fdisk file finalrd findutils fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core fonts-liberation fuse fwupd fwupd-signed fwupdate g++ g++-9 galera-3 gawk gcc gcc-10-base gcc-11-base gcc-8-base gcc-9 gcc-9-base gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2-common gdisk geoip-database gettext-base gir1.2-glib-2.0 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 git git-lfs git-man glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm gpgv grep groff-base grub-common grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed grub-legacy-ec2 grub2-common gsettings-desktop-schemas gsettings-ubuntu-schemas gtk-update-icon-cache gzip haveged hdparm hicolor-icon-theme hostname htop humanity-icon-theme ieee-data im-config init init-system-helpers initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools-core inotify-tools intel-microcode iotop iproute2 iptables iputils-ping iputils-tracepath irqbalance isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common iso-codes iucode-tool iw javascript-common kbd keyboard-configuration klibc-utils kmod krb5-locales language-pack-en language-pack-en-base ldap-auth-client ldap-auth-config ldap-utils less libacl1 libaio1 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libapparmor1 libappindicator1 libappstream4 libapr1 libaprutil1 libapt-pkg6.0 libarchive13 libargon2-0 libargon2-1 libasan5 libasn1-8-heimdal libasound2 libasound2-data libassuan0 libatasmart4 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatm1 libatomic1 libatspi2.0-0 libattr1 libaudit-common libaudit1 libauthen-sasl-perl libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libb2-1 libbind9-160 libbinutils libblas3 libblkid1 libblockdev-crypto2 libblockdev-fs2 libblockdev-loop2 libblockdev-part-err2 libblockdev-part2 libblockdev-swap2 libblockdev-utils2 libblockdev2 libboost-iostreams1.71.0 libbrotli1 libbsd0 libburn4 libbz2-1.0 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc-devtools libc6 libc6-dev libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libcap-ng0 libcap2 libcap2-bin libcbor0.6 libcc1-0 libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libclamav9 libcolord2 libcom-err2 libconfig-inifiles-perl libcpufreq0 libcrack2 libcrypt-dev libcrypt1 libcryptsetup12 libctf-nobfd0 libctf0 libcups2 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 libcwidget4 libdata-dump-perl libdatrie1 libdb5.3 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libdbus-1-3 libdbus-glib-1-2 libdbusmenu-glib4 libdbusmenu-gtk4 libdconf1 libdebconfclient0 libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libdevmapper1.02.1 libdns-export1100 libdns-export1109 libdns1100 libdpkg-perl libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-common libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libedit2 libefiboot1 libefivar1 libelf1 libencode-locale-perl libepoxy0 liberror-perl libestr0 libev4 libevdev2 libevent-2.1-6 libevent-2.1-7 libevent-core-2.1-7 libexpat1 libexpat1-dev libext2fs2 libfakeroot libfastjson4 libfcgi-perl libfdisk1 libffi6 libffi7 libfido2-1 libfile-basedir-perl libfile-desktopentry-perl libfile-fcntllock-perl libfile-listing-perl libfile-mimeinfo-perl libfont-afm-perl libfontconfig1 libfontenc1 libfreetype6 libfribidi0 libfuse2 libfuse3-3 libfwupd2 libfwupdplugin1 libgail-common libgail18 libgcab-1.0-0 libgcc-9-dev libgcc-s1 libgconf-2-4 libgcrypt20 libgd3 libgdbm-compat4 libgdbm5 libgdbm6 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgeoip1 libgetdns10 libgirepository-1.0-1 libgl1 libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data libglvnd0 libglx-mesa0 libglx0 libgmp10 libgnutls30 libgomp1 libgpg-error-l10n libgpg-error0 libgpgme11 libgpm2 libgraphite2-3 libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssapi3-heimdal libgstreamer1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common libgudev-1.0-0 libgusb2 libharfbuzz0b libhavege1 libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal libhiredis0.14 libhogweed4 libhogweed5 libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-template-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libhx509-5-heimdal libice6 libicu60 libicu66 libidn11 libidn2-0 libimagequant0 libimobiledevice6 libinotifytools0 libintl-perl libintl-xs-perl libio-html-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl libio-stringy-perl libip4tc0 libip4tc2 libip6tc0 libip6tc2 libipc-system-simple-perl libiptc0 libirs160 libisc-export1105 libisc-export169 libisc169 libisccc160 libisccfg160 libisl22 libisns0 libisoburn1 libisofs6 libitm1 libjansson4 libjbig0 libjcat1 libjemalloc2 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libjs-jquery libjson-c3 libjson-c4 libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-common libjte2 libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libklibc libkmod2 libkrb5-26-heimdal libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libksba8 liblcms2-2 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common liblinear4 libllvm10 libllvm12 liblmdb0 liblocale-gettext-perl liblsan0 libltdl7 liblua5.1-0 liblua5.3-0 liblvm2app2.2 liblvm2cmd2.02 liblvm2cmd2.03 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl liblwres160 liblxc-common liblxc1 liblz4-1 liblzma5 liblzo2-2 libmagic-mgc libmagic1 libmailtools-perl libmaxminddb0 libmnl0 libmodule-find-perl libmodule-scandeps-perl libmount1 libmpc3 libmpdec2 libmpfr6 libmspack0 libmysqlclient21 libncurses5 libncurses6 libncursesw5 libncursesw6 libnet-dbus-perl libnet-http-perl libnet-smtp-ssl-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libnetfilter-conntrack3 libnettle6 libnettle7 libnewt0.52 libnfnetlink0 libnftables1 libnftnl11 libnghttp2-14 libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext libnginx-mod-http-echo libnginx-mod-http-geoip libnginx-mod-http-geoip2 libnginx-mod-http-image-filter libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter libnginx-mod-mail libnginx-mod-stream libnih1 libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnotify-bin libnotify4 libnpth0 libnsl-dev libnsl2 libnspr4 libnss-ldap libnss-nis libnss-nisplus libnss-systemd libnss3 libnuma1 libodbc1 libp11-kit0 libpackagekit-glib2-18 libpam-cap libpam-ccreds libpam-cracklib libpam-google-authenticator libpam-ldap libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam-runtime libpam-systemd libpam0g libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libparted-fs-resize0 libparted2 libpcap0.8 libpci3 libpciaccess0 libpcre2-8-0 libpcre3 libperl5.26 libperl5.30 libpipeline1 libpixman-1-0 libplist3 libplymouth4 libpng16-16 libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libpopt0 libpq5 libproc-processtable-perl libprocps6 libprocps8 libproxy1v5 libpsl5 libpython2-stdlib libpython2.7 libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib libpython3.6-minimal libpython3.6-stdlib libpython3.8 libpython3.8-dev libpython3.8-minimal libpython3.8-stdlib libpython3.9 libpython3.9-dev libpython3.9-minimal libpython3.9-stdlib libqrencode3 libqrencode4 libquadmath0 libreadline5 libreadline7 libreadline8 librest-0.7-0 libroken18-heimdal librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common librtmp1 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libsasl2-modules-ldap libseccomp2 libselinux1 libsemanage-common libsemanage1 libsensors-config libsensors5 libsepol1 libsepol2 libserf-1-1 libsigc++-2.0-0v5 libsigsegv2 libslang2 libsm6 libsmartcols1 libsmbios-c2 libsnappy1v5 libsodium23 libsort-naturally-perl libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libsqlite3-0 libss2 libssh-4 libssl-dev libssl1.0.0 libssl1.1 libssl3 libstdc++-9-dev libstdc++6 libstemmer0d libsvn1 libsystemd0 libtasn1-6 libterm-readkey-perl libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtext-wrapi18n-perl libtfm1 libthai-data libthai0 libtie-ixhash-perl libtiff5 libtimedate-perl libtinfo5 libtinfo6 libtirpc-common libtirpc-dev libtirpc3 libtry-tiny-perl libtsan0 libtss2-esys0 libubsan1 libuchardet0 libudev1 libudisks2-0 libunbound8 libunistring2 libupower-glib3 liburi-perl libusb-1.0-0 libusbmuxd6 libutempter0 libutf8proc2 libuuid1 libuv1 libvolume-key1 libvulkan1 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1 libwebp6 libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux3 libwind0-heimdal libwmf0.2-7 libwmf0.2-7-gtk libwrap0 libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libx11-6 libx11-data libx11-protocol-perl libx11-xcb1 libxapian30 libxau6 libxaw7 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-sync1 libxcb-xfixes0 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxft2 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxkbfile1 libxml-parser-perl libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpathengine-perl libxml2 libxmlb1 libxmu6 libxmuu1 libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxslt1.1 libxss1 libxt6 libxtables12 libxtst6 libxv1 libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1 libyaml-0-2 libzstd1 linux-base linux-firmware linux-generic linux-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-headers-5.13.0-30-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-18 linux-headers-5.15.0-18-generic linux-headers-generic linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-30 linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic linux-image-5.15.0-18-generic linux-image-generic linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-libc-dev linux-modules-5.13.0-30-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-18-generic linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-30-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-18-generic lm-sensors locales locate login logrotate logsave lsb-base lsb-release lshw lsof lua-bitop lua-cjson lua-lpeg lvm2 lynis lz4 make man-db manpages manpages-dev mariadb-client-10.3 mariadb-client-core-10.3 mariadb-common mariadb-server mariadb-server-10.3 mariadb-server-core-10.3 matrix-synapse matrix-synapse-ldap3 mawk mdadm mesa-vulkan-drivers mime-support mokutil mount mtr multiarch-support mysql-common nano ncurses-base ncurses-bin ncurses-term needrestart nessus nessusagent net-tools netbase netcat-openbsd nethogs nftables nginx-common nginx-full nmap nmap-common nodejs nscd open-iscsi openssh-client openssh-server openssh-sftp-server openssl overlayroot packagekit packagekit-tools parted passwd patch pci.ids pciutils pcmciautils perl perl-base perl-modules-5.26 perl-modules-5.30 perl-openssl-defaults pigz pinentry-curses policykit-1 postgresql postgresql-12 postgresql-client-12 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common powermgmt-base powertop procps psmisc publicsuffix python-apt-common python-pip-whl python-pkg-resources python-setuptools python2 python2-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal python3 python3-apparmor python3-apt python3-asn1crypto python3-attr python3-automat python3-bcrypt python3-bleach python3-bs4 python3-canonicaljson python3-certifi python3-cffi-backend python3-chardet python3-click python3-colorama python3-constantly python3-cryptography python3-daemonize python3-dbus python3-decorator python3-dev python3-distro-info python3-distupgrade python3-distutils python3-frozendict python3-gi python3-hamcrest python3-html5lib python3-httplib2 python3-hyperlink python3-idna python3-importlib-metadata python3-incremental python3-jinja2 python3-jsonschema python3-ldap3 python3-lib2to3 python3-libapparmor python3-llfuse python3-lxml python3-markupsafe python3-minimal python3-more-itertools python3-msgpack python3-nacl python3-netaddr python3-olefile python3-openssl python3-pam python3-phonenumbers python3-pil python3-pip python3-pkg-resources python3-prometheus-client python3-psycopg2 python3-pyasn1 python3-pyasn1-modules python3-pyinotify python3-pymacaroons python3-pyrsistent python3-requests python3-requests-unixsocket python3-serial python3-service-identity python3-setuptools python3-signedjson python3-simplejson python3-six python3-software-properties python3-sortedcontainers python3-soupsieve python3-systemd python3-treq python3-twisted python3-twisted-bin python3-typing-extensions python3-unpaddedbase64 python3-update-manager python3-urllib3 python3-venv python3-webencodings python3-wheel python3-yaml python3-zipp python3-zope.interface python3.6 python3.6-minimal python3.8 python3.8-dev python3.8-minimal python3.8-venv python3.9 python3.9-dev python3.9-minimal rar rclone readline-common redis-server redis-tools rpcsvc-proto rsync rsyslog sasl2-bin sbsigntool secureboot-db sed sensible-utils shared-mime-info shim-signed slapd slirp4netns snapd socat software-properties-common sqlite3 squashfs-tools ssl-cert stubby subversion sudo sysstat systemd systemd-sysv sysvinit-utils tar tcpdump thermald thin-provisioning-tools time tmux tpm-udev tzdata ubuntu-advantage-tools ubuntu-keyring ubuntu-mono ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ucf udev udisks2 uidmap unattended-upgrades unzip update-manager-core upower usb.ids usbmuxd usbutils util-linux uuid-runtime veeam veeam-release-deb veeamsnap wamerican wget whiptail whois wireless-regdb wondershaper x11-common x11-utils x11-xserver-utils xauth xdg-utils xkb-data xorriso xz-utils zerofree zip zlib1g zlib1g-dev zstd
2022-03-07 23:49:14,864 DEBUG Upgradable, but held- back: 
2022-03-07 23:49:14,864 DEBUG Remove: 
2022-03-07 23:49:14,864 DEBUG Install: 
2022-03-07 23:49:14,864 DEBUG Upgrade: 
2022-03-07 23:49:14,869 DEBUG apt btrfs snapshots supported: False
2022-03-07 23:49:14,870 DEBUG cache aufs_rw_dir: /tmp/
2022-03-07 23:49:14,870 DEBUG Free space on /: 47908925440
2022-03-07 23:49:14,870 DEBUG Dir /usr mounted on /
2022-03-07 23:49:14,870 DEBUG Dir /var mounted on /
2022-03-07 23:49:14,870 DEBUG Free space on /boot: 126469120
2022-03-07 23:49:14,870 DEBUG Dir /var/cache/apt/archives mounted on /
2022-03-07 23:49:14,870 DEBUG Dir /tmp mounted on /
2022-03-07 23:49:14,870 DEBUG Dir /home mounted on /
2022-03-07 23:49:14,870 DEBUG Dir /tmp mounted on /
2022-03-07 23:49:14,870 DEBUG fs_free contains: '{'/': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feded096ac0>, '/usr': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feded096ac0>, '/var': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feded096ac0>, '/boot': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feded096e50>, '/var/cache/apt/archives': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feded096ac0>, '/tmp': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feded096ac0>, '/home': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feded096ac0>}'
2022-03-07 23:49:15,114 DEBUG dir '/var/cache/apt/archives' needs '0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feded096ac0>' (47908925440.000000)
2022-03-07 23:49:15,114 DEBUG dir '/usr' needs '0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feded096ac0>' (47908925440.000000)
2022-03-07 23:49:15,114 DEBUG dir '/var' needs '0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feded096ac0>' (47908925440.000000)
2022-03-07 23:49:15,114 DEBUG dir '/usr' needs '52428800' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feded096ac0>' (47908925440.000000)
2022-03-07 23:49:15,114 DEBUG dir '/boot' needs '96588247.35' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feded096e50>' (126469120.000000)
2022-03-07 23:49:15,114 DEBUG dir '/tmp' needs '5242880' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feded096ac0>' (47856496640.000000)
2022-03-07 23:49:15,114 DEBUG dir '/' needs '10485760' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feded096ac0>' (47851253760.000000)
2022-03-07 23:49:15,114 DEBUG dir '/tmp' needs '0.0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feded096ac0>' (47840768000.000000)
2022-03-07 23:49:15,114 DEBUG dir '/usr' needs '0.0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feded096ac0>' (47840768000.000000)
2022-03-07 23:49:15,115 DEBUG Found writable ESP /dev/sdb2 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
2022-03-07 23:49:15,116 DEBUG demoted: 'libasn1-8-heimdal libgssapi3-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libidn11 libkrb5-26-heimdal libroken18-heimdal libwind0-heimdal'
2022-03-07 23:49:15,117 DEBUG found components: {'jammy': {'universe', 'multiverse', 'main', 'restricted'}, 'jammy-updates': {'universe', 'multiverse', 'main', 'restricted'}, 'jammy-security': {'universe', 'multiverse', 'main', 'restricted'}}
2022-03-07 23:49:15,117 DEBUG abort called
2022-03-07 23:49:15,117 DEBUG openCache()
2022-03-07 23:49:16,320 DEBUG Comparing 5.13.0-30 with 
2022-03-07 23:49:16,320 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-18 with 5.13.0-30
2022-03-07 23:49:16,391 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 66479
```

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc.  *This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*   Upgrades to *jammy* are still QA-testing involved & issues encountered at this stage can be fixed; but this isn't a site used to track *jammy* issues.

Comment: The upgrade isn't failing because of a bug in Jammy, it's failing because of an issue with my 20.04 install. The same issue happens if I try to upgrade to 21.10

Comment: Additionally all of the releases between 20.04 and 21.10 are already EOL, so those upgrade paths are no longer supported.  20.04 to 22.04 is not yet supported. And the upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 will not be offered until the first point release (22.04.1) which typically will not be released until several months after 22.04 has its initial release.  So if you are wondering why you can't upgrade 20.04, it's because there is no supported upgrade path at this time.  You are already on the most recent release in that channel

Comment: An upgrade from *focal* to *impish* would be on-topic here, but your paste shows *jammy* which is off-topic as *unsupported* here as per site rules. Ubuntu *jammy* upgrade questions will be on-topic when it's supported, which is still in the future for this site.

Comment: Are you at least able to tell me how I can troubleshoot this myself, and where I should start?

Comment: Details on this web site as you provided are difficult to read; I find the reports on launchpad far easier (*or reading it locally*) but you're off-topic here with anything related to *jammy* which this question/paste is about.

Comment: @Nmath already answered answered this question: There is currently no supported do-release-upgrade path from 20.04. There *was*, from 20.04 to 20.10...but that path is now closed. There *will be* from 20.04 to 22.04...but that path is not open yet. It is likely to open in July 2022.